# Why does the "submit" button display before the <form>?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, dom, view

This is kind of surprising. Even though it looks to me like my submit tag is supposed to occur within the form, it displays before the form. The html source looks ok to me, but the resultant display and DOM is wrong. Not sure what would have shuffled it. The submit button is displayed BEFORE the form.

Can you see something?

view file:

```
<%= content_tag :table do %>
  <%= content_tag :thead do %>
    <% 5.times do |q| %>
      <%= content_tag :th, "1" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= content_tag :tbody do %>
    <%= form_tag program_participant_round_survey_path(
        program_id: @program.id, participant_id: @participant.id, round_id: @current_round.id), :method => 'put'  do %>
      <%= render partial: 'value', collection: @values  %>
      <%= submit_tag "Save" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

key part of the html:

```
...
<tr>
  <td>
    Scaling Up vs. Scaling Out
</td>
    <td>
      <input id="values__q0" name="values[]" type="radio" value="q0" />
</td>    <td>
      <input id="values__q1" name="values[]" type="radio" value="q1" />
</td>    <td>
      <input id="values__q2" name="values[]" type="radio" value="q2" />
</td>    <td>
      <input id="values__q3" name="values[]" type="radio" value="q3" />
</td></tr>
      <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form></tbody></table>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what the page looks like in the browser: [image: image in browser]

And here's what it looks like as DOM: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how a browser handles elements inside tables that don't belong there - it assumes they're a caption and moves them before the table.

You have a `<input type="submit">` inside a table but not inside a `<tr>` in the generated code.

If you wrap the `<input>` in `<tr><td>`, it will no longer move before the table. Note that using tables for layout is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact reason for what's happening, but I would personally do it like this instead:

```
<%= form_tag program_participant_round_survey_path(
        program_id: @program.id, participant_id: @participant.id, round_id: @current_round.id), :method => 'put'  do %>
  <%= content_tag :table do %>
    <%= content_tag :thead do %>
      <% 5.times do |q| %>
        <%= content_tag :th, "1" %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= content_tag :tbody do %>        
      <%= render partial: 'value', collection: @values  %> 
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Also, this is a matter of taste and not directly relevant to your question, but instead of `<%= content_tag :table do %>`, etc., I would just do `<table>`. I bet your markup would be easier to read and you'd be less susceptible to the kind of problem you're having now.

Comment: Interesting point @jason -- I assumed that using the content_tag was giving me some rails magic but you're right the straight tags would be easier to read!